# How to get worked Animation.css in Angular 1.5.8?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, animation, css-animations

I've added a dependency `ngAnimate` to AngularJS:

```
var app=angular.module('testApp',['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate']);
```

and I've added the animations classes to `animation.css`:

```
.slide-animation.ng-enter, .slide-animation.ng-leave {
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s linear all;
    -moz-transition: 0.5s linear all;
    -o-transition: 0.5s linear all;
    transition: 0.5s linear all;
    position:relative;
    height: 1000px;
}
```

and included this CSS file in the head:

```
<head>              
    <link href="app/styles/animations.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
```

Then I've used this class in my `index.html` file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="testApp">
<head>
    <title>Foo App</title>              
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
                rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>      
    <link href="app/styles/animations.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body >         

    <div ng-view="" class="slide-animation"></div>       

    <script src="scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/angular-route.js"></script> 
    <script src="scripts/angular-animate.js"></script> 
    <script src="app/app.js"></script>
    <script src="app/controllers/employeeController.js"> </script>
    <script src="app/controllers/depController.js"></script>
    <script src="app/services/employeeFactory.js"/></script>
</body>
```

However, there is no slide animation.

I've seen this [tutorial](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/angularjs-animations-in-version-1-2) and my actions are the same to get used animations from the `animation.css` file.

**Please, does anybody know what I've missed?**

Comment: are the classes added correctly?

Comment: @HorstJahns in my view, `class` is added correctly. Is this code snippet not enough?

Comment: Are you sure scripts/angular-animate.js is in correct location? In console did you got some errors?

Comment: @SimoEndre you're right! No errors in console. You've pushed me to use debugger and I've seen that there's no inject of 'ngAnimate'. It happens because of I confuesed files. Feel free to answer and I'll mark it. Thanks for your effort!:)

Comment: @StepUp no problem, it happens :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if `scripts/angular-animate.js` is loaded. You can verify this by inspecting the file existence in the source or the network panel in every browser.

From what you described `angular-animate.js` file is not included into the document, that's why the `ngAnimate` directive is not working.

Answer (score 1):

I think you missed `ng-app`.
Place `ng-app="app"` on `BODY` or `HTML` as attribute.
and place the ng-animate on the `div` like this.

```
<body ng-app="app">      
   <div ng-view="" class="slide-animation" ng-animate="animate"></div>
<body>
```

CSS:

```
.slide-animation {
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 560px;
}
.slide-animation.ng-enter  .ng-enter-active, .slide-animation.ng-leave {
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s linear all;
    -moz-transition: 0.5s linear all;
    -o-transition: 0.5s linear all;
    transition: 0.5s linear all;
    position:relative;
    height: 1000px;
}
```

Then I think it will be works

Comment: oops, sorry for misleading. However,  I have `ng-app` directive. Please, see my updated question.

Comment: Did you try ng-animate="'animate'" ?

Comment: yeap, nothing happens